# Required Picklist from Custom Object view

Tags: apex, validation, custom-object, required-field

When you add an new field to an object in Salesforce.com, it is possible to check the "Required" checkbox to make it mandatory for every data insert/update. I know it is possible to make it required from a layout, but these conditions are not applied when inserting or updating the database from an Apex code.

Is there a reason why there's no way to do the same with a picklist field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there is a reason why it is not possible, but no, it is not possible to set it required as part of the custom field.

If you absolutely must make it required, provide a default value and/or write a validation rule that verifies that a value is selected on insert and update. This should ensure that a value is always associated to that field.

Here is the validation rule you need:

```
ISPICKVAL(Test_Value__c,'')
```

where Test_Value__c is the API name of your field.

Comment: How do you plan to check something is filled in with a "workflow rule"... Is that a typo?

Comment: Ok, then I'm deleting mine and giving you +1, I thought you're really answering in some harebrained workflow-y way. But `ISBLANK` works just fine on multiselect picklists ;)

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing right now, using a validation rule. I really don't get it, this should be a built-in feature to preserve data integrity. I'll wait to see if somebody else has another answer to justify the reason behind this.

Comment: I would assume it is related to fact that picklists have the --None-- value when no default option is selected and/or the fact that dependent picklists exit.  This is just speculation as I have no idea how they store all of that data under the covers. Hopefully someone else has a good idea of why it isn't base functionality.

Comment: `--None--` is the value displayed when the field in the database is null.